# How to create storage agnostic bundle in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Can somebody explain how to create storage agnostic bundle in Symfony2? There is no documentation about it over the Internet, and this recipe: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/mapping_model_classes.html is not enough!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at existing bundles. [FOSUserBundle](http://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) is a good example.

Basically you create a common Model-class which your storage-specific Entities or Documents (or whatever) extend. The same goes for your Mappers and/or Repositories (if you have any).

A good way to keep from repeating yourself and having a reusable base is to use `Doctrine\Common`, which is agnostic and for obvious reasons your base classes are compatible with Doctrine ORM and ODM.

**edit for clarification:**
The above cookbook-entry just manages which Mappers, Repositories, Entities, and so on are actually used depending on your configuration, i.e. which persistence (ORM, ODM, PHPCR) you choose. This way, you always expose (which might be important if other bundles rely on it) your, for example UserManager, with `fos_user.user_manager` whether its actually your ORMUserManager, ODMUserManager or PHPCRUserManager you are using. Additionally you have the ability to provide storage-sepcific helpers, e.g. certain EventListeners for each different configuration.